# Remove core data file on copy and paste to other project Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

I am working on Xcode 5.0 and with core data. I spend 2 to 3hrs for making relation with tables and those are 2 dozens of table. Now what happened I need those relation for other project also, I copy and paste this to other project both project "xcdatamodeld" file remove and show in red color in compile resource. I don't know why this happen. Kindly guide me if someone already faced this sort of problem. And if there is no chance to recover then also guide me how to add new one. I also made search on whole my mac but didn't find that file. 
I am looking for your response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the future: start using a version control system. XCode automatically creates a git repo for you for each new project.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to properly copy the original file of datamodel to the destination project and add it as usual file..that's it.

When adding the file don't forget to tick the checkbox:
[image]

Comment: Yeah, this I've to do but what to do now, If I lost that I think so?

Comment: you've lost original file or what?

Comment: Yes I've lost original file, that what I discussing on above question that I lost original and copy too by copying and paste :( I don't know  why this happened.

Comment: Tro to find this file in trash..or create new..there're no other options..and be careful in the future )